# Safari XHR upload stucks (sometimes)

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload, xmlhttprequest

I build a upload script using [jquery-File-Upload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload).

Now I have the weird behavior that the upload stucks from time to time (let's say every eighth time). This only happens in Safari (5.0.5), other browsers are working fine.

I can confirm that this is NOT server related. The problem accours before any server scripts are executed.

Sometimes the upload stucks at 2%, sometimes at 82%.

Also I find it hard to debug. When using [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) the problem seams to disappear.

Any help regarding the issue and debugging strategies appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out that [this solution](http://www.icyte.com/system/snapshots/fs1/c/7/2/7/c72720220216a763a70c70f8357eaf233302252e/index.html#comment-165189058) by [Ben](http://twitter.com/benmarsh) fixes the issue.

In case you use [jquery-File-Upload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload) it looks like this (caution: i'm using the [v4 version](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/tree/v4)):

```
$(function () {
        $('#file_upload').fileUploadUI({
            //some other code
            beforeSend: function (event, files, index, xhr, handler, callBack) {
                $.ajax({
                    async: false,
                    url: 'closeconnection.php'
                });
                callBack();
            }
        });
    });
```

Where the corresponding php script looks like this:

```
<?php
    header("Connection: Close");
?>
```

WTF??

Does this has something to do with Safari caching? Or with [still open POST requests](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=64739)? Let me know if you have any idea...

Comment: I am using an other file upload plugin, but had the same problem with an occasional 'hanging' Safari ajax request. This beforeSend-solution seems to be solving these issues, thanks!