# valums Ajax upload not working on Safari

Tags: jquery

I'm using valums Ajax upload to upload images. I have mulitple upload buttons on the same page. Everything works perfect on FF, Chrome, IE8 and Opera. But, in safari nothing happens and also file is not uploaded. I'm using ajaxupload.3.6.js and below is my code -

```
        button = $("#uplaodFile1");      
             new AjaxUpload(button, {
            action : '/business/upload_file1',
            name: 'uplaodFile1',
            autoSubmit: true,
            cache:false,
            onSubmit: function (file, ext) {

                if (!(ext && /^(jpg|gif|png)$/i.test(ext))) {
                    alert('Error: invalid file extension');
                    return false;
                }

            },
            onComplete: function (file, response) {
               if(response=="Sucess") {
                    alert(response + 'sucess');
                    }

                else {
                        alert(response);
                    }

            }
        });
```

Has anybody faced this. I tried all the options like adding the meta tag, searching for empty src attribute and url attribute also, but nothing could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its known issues with safari browser.Please check this link https://github.com/valums/file-uploader/issues/190.You can try http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/ this plugin its has good good features and documentation

Comment: I tried to this plugin and could test it successfully on Safari 5, but I'm not able to add callbacks. Kindly help me if you have used this before.

Answer (score 0):

It is an old question, but this is still a really annoying Safari problem. See [Safari XHR upload stucks (sometimes)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6491512/safari-xhr-upload-stucks-sometimes) and [JQuery Ajax call often not working on Safari 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18778814/jquery-ajax-call-often-not-working-on-safari-6/18821423#18821423).

The good new is: you can build the proposed workaround explained in the provided links in Valums fileuploader.js:

How? Add an ajax call in the function _upload before the`xhr.open` of the plugin qq.FileUploader and include all code untill xhr.send in the ajax' succes function:

```
$.ajax({
   async: false,
   url: your_closeconnection_script
})
.success(function(data){
   xhr.open(...
   ...
   xhr.send(file);
});
```

One more thing: You need to create a variable of 'this' before the ajax call and replace **all** occurrences in the success function:

```
var $this = this;
$.ajax({
   async: false,
   url: your_closeconnection_script
})
.success(function(data){
   xhr.open(...
   ...
   if ($this._options.encoding == 'multipart'){
      ...
   }
   ...
   xhr.send(file);
});
```

Et voila: a smooth working Valums plugin!