# JQuery Ajax call often not working on Safari 6

Tags: ajax, jquery, safari

My Ajax call is really simple as below:

```
function ajax(reqUrl, params , callback) {
console.log("Request URL "+reqUrl);
var cond;
cond = $.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: reqUrl,
    data: params,
    error:function(){ alert("some error occurred") },
    success: callback
});
console.log("Server response "+cond.readyState);
}
   // Call it as 
    var url = "/getResult";
    var params = {};
    params.param1 = "test1";
    params.param2 = "test2";
    ajax(url, params, function(returnCallback) {
        console.log(returnCallback);
        alert("Success");
    });
```

That works fine in most cases. But sometimes (about 1 times in 3) it doesn't return anything to callback.

I found many questions and answers for **Not working ajax in Safari but fine in chrome and FireFox**. My problem is ***different from them, because it's fine most of the time*** (I don't mean it was not fine usually because when I refresh my browser, that may cause my ajax call to work).

My main question is why does my ajax call sometimes fail? I don't get any errors on my JS console. When this situation, I refresh my browser to get my ajax call to. Any Ideas?

**Update:**

I found that sometimes my ajax call method didn't call out because **console.log("Request URL "+reqUrl);** did not execute. When I don't want to refresh my browser, I clicked many times on my page's link to produce result. will something late to execute?

Comment: My problem does not occur in chrome and firefox. Just often in Safari :(. I really want to know why ?

Comment: don't be defined it as Duplicated if you really don't know what I mean.

Comment: And I described as an example codes. Don't be assume it is really full code that I use.

Comment: I found one , Safari has not reload js files by anchor links of my pages.

Comment: Really I need to refresh to reinvoke js files .. why ?

Comment: This seems to be a Safari issue. See [this post][1] for a 'beforeSend'-solution.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6491512/safari-xhr-upload-stucks-sometimes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally, I found error .. Safari doesn't reload my JavaScript files again even disable Cache. So I put all of my JS code into:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 // start load my js functions
 init();
});
```

to reload my JS files when my page was ready. Cheer !

Answer (score 2):

I also met this problem.

When I moved all code into `$(function() {})`, it worked.

After that, I found I had defined a variable named `key`, which caused the problem.

Just rename it, all things will be running.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a Safari issue. In [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6491512/safari-xhr-upload-stucks-sometimes) there is a suggestion to add a beforeSend to your ajax-request.

In your case:

```
cond = $.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: reqUrl,
    data: params,
    beforeSend: function (event, files, index, xhr, handler, callBack) {
         $.ajax({
             async: false,
             url: 'closeconnection.php' // add path
         });
    },
    error:function(){ alert("some error occurred") },
    success: callback
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please Test below Code. it is working fine.

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url:'@Url.Action("getResult","Controller")', 
data: "{userName :'" + userName  + "',password :'" + password + "' }",
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
dataType: "html",
success: function (data) {
alert("here" + data.toString());
});
```

Comment: When I add contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", that produce in my code as Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request).

Comment: url:'@Url.Action("getResult","Controller")',  what is it's definition and how to pass my url in it.

Answer (score 0):

This is use for MVC application.

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url:'getResult', 
data: "{userName :'" + userName  + "',password :'" + password + "' }",
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
dataType: "json",
success: function (data) {
alert("here" + data.toString());
});
```

For Asp.net Application :

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url:'getResult', 
data: "{userName :'" + userName  + "',password :'" + password + "' }",
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
dataType: "json",
success: function (data) {
alert("here" + data.toString());
});
```

if u have still the  issue than please post ur complete code here. i will test and reply soon