# Ajax request blank response only happening in Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, safari

Chrome and Firefox are able to handle the responses from below requests just fine, Safari is giving problems.

Coffescript examples:

```
$.get "https://mtgox.com/api/1/BTCEUR/ticker", (data) ->
  console.log(data)
```

The above request works and yields a json response (even in Safari).

The request below doesn't get a response in the console (Safari):

```
$.get "https://api.bitcoinaverage.com/ticker/EUR", (data) ->
  console.log(data)
```

The only difference I can spot is the json structure.
Is there a workaround for this problem?

Comment: [Some research](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18778814/jquery-ajax-call-often-not-working-on-safari-6) suggests that older safari's don't always reload the JS file. Have you checked to make sure that your file is actually changing in the browser?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the JS AFAIK, try a JS fiddle in Safari and you'll see the second ajax request written in my question won't work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`https://api.bitcoinaverage.com/ticker/EUR` is responding with a redirect to `https://api.bitcoinaverage.com/ticker/EUR/` (note the trailing slash).

I'm not quite sure what exactly Safari's issue is with this, but it appears to be losing the CORS headers when it does the redirect.

If you make the request with the trailing slash it works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/8XR3u/2/