# jQuery click function is not working on window safari browser

Tags: jquery

I have the following code working fine everywhere except Safari on Windows. Any suggestions how to fix it?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    // show the form
    // alert("hello");

    //jQuery(".tab3").attr('disabled', true);
    jQuery(".tab2").attr('disabled', false);
    jQuery(".tab3").attr('checked', true);
    jQuery(".tab2").attr('disabled', true);
    jQuery(".tab3").click();
    jQuery(".popUp").children('a').get(0).click();
});
```

Comment: And this is tagged as php because?

Comment: I am doing this code in php file.

Comment: @ Rory McCrossan code stop working in all browser after adding your code. Thanks for reply.

Comment: No its not working I have tried this

Comment: Show what are the elements `.tab2`, `.tab3` etc.

Comment: This code is working fine on all browser except window safari.Even this is working on mac safari also.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery .click() works on every browser but Safari](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12925153/jquery-click-works-on-every-browser-but-safari)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery(".tab2").attr('disabled', false);
    jQuery(".tab3").attr('checked', true);
    jQuery(".tab2").attr('disabled', true);
    var a1 = jQuery(".tab3");
    var a2 = jQuery(".popUp").children('a').get(0);
    var evObj1 = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
    evObj1.initMouseEvent('click', true, true, window);
    var evObj2 = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
    evObj2.initMouseEvent('click', true, true, window);

    a1.dispatchEvent(evObj1);
    a2.dispatchEvent(evObj2);
});
```

Source: [jQuery .click() works on every browser but Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12925153/jquery-click-works-on-every-browser-but-safari/12925565#12925565)

Comment: Please, can you tell me where is the error so I can edit my answer. It can help other people with the same problem who arribes here.

Comment: I have just commented  var a1 = jQuery(".tab3"); and  a1.dispatchEvent(evObj);

Comment: But then `.tab3` click event isn't triggering, right?

Comment: I've edited my answer to create a new event object. If works, please consider accept my answer.

Comment: I have the same issue with ajax jQuery.ajax is not working on window safari.

Comment: Do you have any solution why ajax jQuery.ajax is not working on window safari.

Comment: You upvoted my answer, not [accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it :) 
You should open a new question, anyways look at this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18778814/jquery-ajax-call-often-not-working-on-safari-6)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91395/discussion-between-campsjos-and-rakesh).