# Ajax get request not working in safari with HTTPS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, https

I want to load some template files dynamically with the help of ajax. I have added the ajax `$.get` method for loading the html files and it's working fine with all browsers except safari browser.

In safari it gives me **"Failed to load resource: cancelled"** error when first time I open the url. However after I refresh my page again, it loads all the files.

When I open my url with http request instead of https, it can load the template file in first time on safari browser.

This issue only happens when I open the url with **https**. I have successfully installed the certificate and its working fine with other browser. Even there is no certificate issue in safari as well.

Here is my code

```
var decorator = {
  init: function(book, cd) {
    this.loadTPL(cd);
  },
  tpl: {
    btnStart: "tpl/startBtn.html",
    interfaceTpl: "tpl/interfaceTpl.html",
    topMenu: "tpl/topMenu.html",
    topMenuItem: "tpl/topMenuItem.html",
  },
  loadTPL: function(cbTpl) {
    var self = this;
    var objTpl = {};

    async.forEachOf(this.tpl, function(value, key, callback) {
      $.get(value, {}, function(data) {
        //alert("Load was performed.");
        //console.log(value, data);
        objTpl[key] = data;
        callback();
      });

    }, function(err, results) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
      self.tpl = objTpl;
      cbTpl(err);
    });
  }
}
```

Any Idea?

Comment: you can try to resend request when you detect that first sending fail

Comment: @KamilKiełczewski I have tried to resend request but it's not working.its only working when i refresh the page.

Comment: Are you calling https url from https source ?

Comment: @sparshturkane, Yes i am calling https url from https source

Comment: Please update your Post with your current OS, Safari Version, and the Request/Response Headers from Console.

Comment: First, are you using or simulating a proxy server? (Like a Microservices load balancer). Looks like not, but wanted to ask. Second, have you tried changing the Trust from System default to Always trust in your KeyChain?

Comment: Is it working in other browsers? It may be something like CORS too. Have you tried Right click -> Inspect Element -> + (new tab) -> Network -> (for me I am normally getting back .json - click on that in name pane), then have a look at Headers? Paste back some screenshots of that output. PS: If it's something like server sending redirects maybe that could cause hiccups too.

Comment: What is the source of the templates ?

Comment: this is likely a problem with how you pass the parameters, can you give us a request from your inspection tool?

Comment: Is it releated to this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18778814/jquery-ajax-call-often-not-working-on-safari-6

Answer (score 1):

While your approach "should" work, it goes into the weird unknown areas of JS, specially using the async lib. So, my solution basically involves refactoring all of it. Instead async you can use jQuery promises to fire all the gets you need, and then handle the responses/errors in each one of them with the promises handlers.

As an example:

```
$(templatesToLoad).each(function (element, index) {
  $.ajax({element.url, cache: false })
    .done(function (result) {
        objTpl[key] = result;
        element.allback(); // callback for each template
    })
    .fail(function () {
     alert( "error" );
    })
    .always(function () {
     alert( "completed" );
    });
});
```

Note:$.get its just a sugar code for $.ajax. By default $.ajax performs a get, unless another method is specified.

The browser, whichever it is,  will handle the calls and it will trigger each one of them as soon as permitted, based on each browser capabilities and limitations, so no need to worry about specific implementations.

As general rule, always remember to check the encoding of the calls and responses and their formats, json, text or whatever you use as a response format.

Answer (score -1):

This is likely a cache/timeout issue. Try setting the ajax timeout to something huge.  If that works, back it off until you find the sweet spot.